# How to pause video at specific time in Android?

Tags: android, video

I am using VideoView to play *.mp4 file. And I want to play and pause it at a specific time.

Here is my code:

```
VideoView videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("/sdcard/video/myvideo.mp4"));
videoView.seekTo(15000);
videoView.play();
```

In this case, video start from 00:00:15. And I want to pause it at 00:00:30.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final VideoView videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);     
videoView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        videoView.pause();

    }
}, 15000);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the video to pause at exactly 00:00:30 and not just 30 sec after video play, the most reliable way is to have a handler that run every second to check on the current position of the video. Pause the video if the current position is equal or larger than 30 sec.